# How to upload the folder to digital ocean spaces?

Tags: amazon-s3, boto3, digital-ocean, boto, digital-ocean-spaces

From the link, https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-to-upload-an-object-to-digital-ocean-spaces-using-python-boto3-library. It only states to upload files to the spaces.

I want to upload a folder to the spaces.

```
import boto3

session = boto3.session.Session()
client = session.client('s3',
                        region_name='nyc3',
                        endpoint_url='https://nyc3.digitaloceanspaces.com',
                        aws_access_key_id='ACCESS_KEY',
                        aws_secret_access_key='SECRET_KEY')

client.upload_file('/path/to/file.ext',  # Path to local file
                   'my-space',  # Name of Space
                   'file.ext')  # Name for remote file
```

This only uploads file. How to upload folder or directory from this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it the same as with S3, which is to **iterate over the files in the folder** and upload all files as you iterate over them using your `upload_file`.

Only AWS CLI has high level function to upload folders. `boto3` can upload only individual files.

Comment: so I need to create function which iterate over all the files

Comment: @AtomStore Yes. Or look for existing, third party ones, such as https://gist.github.com/hari116/4ab5ebd885b63e699c4662cd8382c314/ . This is a common problem, and there are many boto3 code snippets available for that. You can also use AWS CLI, even from python, if you want.

Answer (score -1):

s3cmd will do the job.

It allows multiple file upload, uploading in chuncks and even sync folder with s3 folder

https://docs.digitalocean.com/products/spaces/reference/s3cmd/